# Groupby and sum in laravel

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I has two tables (application , other) with has many relation

Structure for applicaton table like this:

```
id|date|created_at|updated_at
```

And other table like this :

```
id|application_id|total
```

I want to create report each month , the query i have is just to groupby and i dont know how to sum total from table other.
My query :

```
Application::with('other')->select(DB::raw('YEAR(date) year, MONTH(date) month'))

            ->groupby('year','month')->get();
```

Is any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using either your `Application` model, or the `DB` facade:

```
DB::selectRaw('YEAR(date) AS year, MONTH(date) AS month, SUM(others.total) AS total)
    ->join('others', 'applications.id', '=', 'other.application_id')
    ->groupBy('year', 'month')
    ->get();
```

Comment: application::select(DB::raw('YEAR(date) AS year, MONTH(date) AS month, SUM(other.total) AS total'))
            ->join('other', 'application.id', '=', 'other.aplikasi_id')
            ->groupBy('year', 'month')
            ->get();